# How can I show zeros count?

Tags: looker-studio

I am preparing a report with some data of places and the number of visits to these places by a list of staff. That is, each person has to visit a number of places in the week. I need to show the list of people, the place and count the total visits in the week.

I have two databases, the first one contains the person in charge and the place. And in the other one I have the history of visits where is the person, the week and the place.

However, I want to show the places that are still to be visited in a specific week. But as there is no data int the history database, Google Data Studio does not show anything, I need it to show me the place, week and zeros.

I tried to merge those two databases but I couldn't find solution. The week is numeric and the other are text.

Table 1: visits_history

| Personal | Station | Week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | MOVIL 1 | 30 |
| Person1 | MOVIL 1 | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 30 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Eldorado | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | MOVIL 3 | 31 |
| Person1 | MOVIL 3 | 31 |
| Person1 | Banderas P. Central | 31 |
| Person1 | Banderas P. Central | 31 |
| Person1 | Banderas P. Central | 31 |
| Person1 | Banderas P. Central | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 31 |

Table 2: visits_to_do_per_week

| Supervisor | Punto |
| --- | --- |
| Person1 | Banderas P. Central |
| Person1 | Centro Comercial Gran Plaza Soacha |
| Person1 | Centro Comercial Hayuelos |
| Person1 | Centro Comercial Milenio Plaza |
| Person1 | Movil 1 |
| Person1 | Movil 2 |
| Person1 | Movil 3 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas |
| Person1 | Portal Sur |
| Person1 | Super Cade Bosa |
| Person1 | Zona Franca |

Expected Result:

| person | station_asigment | visits in the week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | Banderas P. Central | 1 |
| Person1 | Centro Comercial Gran Plaza Soacha | 0 |
| Person1 | Centro Comercial Hayuelos | 0 |
| Person1 | Centro Comercial Milenio Plaza | 0 |
| Person1 | Movil 1 | 1 |
| Person1 | Movil 2 | 1 |
| Person1 | Movil 3 | 2 |
| Person1 | Portal Américas | 1 |
| Person1 | Portal Sur | 2 |
| Person1 | Super Cade Bosa | 3 |

[Editable Data Set (Google Sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AvKlYPfNSt_qt3ygo89UCDh9Mtec3cIh8L3uAd06M7o/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `visted` table be as:

| week | person | visited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | Alice | Paris |
| 35 | Bob | Paris |
| 35 | Bob | New York |
| 36 | Alice | Paris |

and the `task` table be:

| person | place |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Paris |
| Alice | Berlin |
| Alice | Amsterdam |
| Bob | Paris |
| Bob | New York |
| Bob | Chicago |
| Claire | Los Angeles |

**Case 1**

I assume that each week the same places have to be visited.

In Data studio create in the `visited` table a slider parameter `week_select` to select a week. Then create a field with

```
week - week_select
```

Create a filter on the table with that field equal zero.

Blend the datasets:
[image]

Add a table chart with `person` and `place` and click twice on the blue plus button under Metric:
[image]

Then add a metric field `visited` with the formula

```
case when Record Count is null then 0 else 1 end
```

You end up with that

[image]

**Case 2**
In the `task` table there is also a week column.

So for each week other places have to be visited. Then there is no need to add the parameter and the week formula and the filter of it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried to build like you do but i can´t make the `week_select` metric. This is an example of the data [link to Google Spreadsheet] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AvKlYPfNSt_qt3ygo89UCDh9Mtec3cIh8L3uAd06M7o/edit?usp=sharing) could you please help me with a example how you did it ?

Comment: first you need to add a parameter `week_select` as number(whole) with a range 0 to 54. Then add a slider and add this parameter to it. You can then select the specific week, which shall be analyzed.